# How does symfony2 inject the profiler?

Tags: symfony

When I use the dev AppKernel of my app symfony shows a profiler bar at the bottom of the site.

How does symphony does this? Does it transparently inject something into my templates? I ask this because when I output raw text with "return new Response" from a controller action no profiler code is appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web profiler is injected during event `kernel.response`.

Precisely it's caused by [`WebDebugToolbarListener.php`](https://github.com/symfony/WebProfilerBundle/blob/master/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php#L56).

It checks if response content type is html and there's no xdebug token header.

Comment: + it only injects the container if it can find the `</body>` tag.